# NSOpenPanel on Main-Thread doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, macos, xcode9

I tried to use `NSOpenPanel` for my program and it doesn't work at all, because the NSOpenpanel doesn't run on the main thread.

Here's my code

```
NSString *strURL;
NSOpenPanel *fileContents;
NSURL *panelURL;
NSArray *fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"strings", @"STRINGS", nil];
fileContents = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[fileContents setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[fileContents setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[fileContents setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
[fileContents setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
NSInteger openPanelButton = [fileContents runModal];

if(openPanelButton == NSModalResponseOK)
{
    panelURL = [fileContents URL];
    strURL = panelURL.absoluteString;
}

NSArray *linesReadOnly = [strURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

I tried both of the following codes:

```
[fileContents performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runModal) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//do UI stuff
});
```

It just doesn't work at all to get this on the main-thread. What do I do wrong?

Comment: As far as Objective-C is concerned, topics for NSOpenPanel have been thoroughly discussed here.  There is nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below code.

```
    //Open pannel to select any file or image and send it to server with upload file API
    let openPannel: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPannel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    openPannel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPannel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPannel.runModal()

    let choosenFile = openPannel.URL
    if choosenFile != nil
    {
        let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(choosenFile?.pathExtension!)!,
                                                        nil)
        if UTTypeConformsTo((uti?.takeRetainedValue())!, kUTTypeImage) {
            print("This is an image!")
        }
        else if UTTypeConformsTo((uti?.takeRetainedValue())!, kUTTypeFolder) {
            print("This is a folder!")
        }
        else if UTTypeConformsTo((uti?.takeRetainedValue())!, kUTTypeAliasFile) {
            print("This is a zip!")
        }
        else if UTTypeConformsTo((uti?.takeRetainedValue())!, kUTTypeSpreadsheet) {
            print("This is a sheet!")
        }
    }
```